# ExtJS 4 - Calling javascript class method from animation listener fails

Tags: javascript, class, extjs, scope

I have a controller that is running some animation on a view.  When the animation is complete, I need to execute a method (called `goToMainApp`) on my controller.  My animation complete listener gets invoked -- no problem there...but the method invocation fails.  Here's the controller:

```
Ext.define('LoginApp.controller.LoginController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config : ....
    init : ......

    goToMainApp : function() {
        console.log('Redirecting to main application');
        do important stuff here....;
    },

    tryLogin : function() {
        this.getCredentialsForm().submit({
            success : function(form, action) {
                console.log('login successful');

                // fade out the login form element
                var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("loginview")[0];
                form.getEl().fadeOut({
                    duration : 500,

                        listeners : {
                            afteranimate : function() {
                                console.log('login successful');  // WORKS!!!
                                this.goToMainApp();  // FAILS!!!
                            }
                    }
                });

            },
            failure : .....
        });
    }
});
```

I think my problem is that the `this` in my call to `this.goToMainApp();` is the animation object and not the controller...but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add scope to your listener:

```
scope: this
```

Example from docs:

```
        tryLogin : function() {
        this.getCredentialsForm().submit({
            scope : this,    // Sets scope of the form handler to the controller
            success : function(form, action) {
                console.log('login successful');

                // fade out the login form element
                var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("loginview")[0];
                form.getEl().fadeOut({
                    duration : 500,

                        listeners : {
                            scope : this, // Now also sets it to controller
                            afteranimate : function() {
                                console.log('login successful');  // WORKS!!!
                                this.goToMainApp();  // FAILS!!!
                            }
                    }
                });

            },
            failure : .....
        });
```

Comment: have you tried inspecting the scope in the call back function, and what is it? there is another trick you could use: var me=this; above submit() and set scope:me

Comment: In the inspector it says that `this` is now the form, whose success handler I am in when I run the `fadeOut`.  So we are getting closer.

Comment: You need to specify the scope for the submit callback as well. Also, there's no point doing me = this and setting the scope, since you already have a reference to the controller via the me variable.

Comment: You are both right.  dbrin's trick worked.  However both of Evan's points were spot on. I needed to add an additional scope:this to the form's success handler...which I did and it worked great.  I'll edit your answer to show what I did and then accept it dbrin.